# Job Advice for Pursuing a Tenure-Track Position in the U.S. (Postdoc in the U.S., Teaching-track/lecturer in the U.S., Tenure-track abroad)

Tags: job-search, job, tenure-track, non-tenure

**Among a tenure-track job in Asia, a teaching track in the U.S., and a postdoc in the U.S., I wonder which options would be better to pursue a tenure-track job in the U.S. eventually?**

Comment: It matters what tenure track job in Asia.  NUS is not equivalent to a third rate university in China.  It also matters what field, and in particular what kind of university support you need for your research.

Comment: Yes, “Asia” is a big place, and US academia is also a big place. I think we need quite a lot more information to have a hope of saying anything useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In many fields and countries, it's rare to get a tenure-track position right after a PhD.  Generally speaking, if you want to go into tenure-track academia, a strong post-doc or two (or three depending on the field), with good publications is an asset, though it is also good to build up a teaching dossier.  I suspect the post-doc would allow you to be a more productive researcher than a starting faculty in the short term, though tenure-track in China probably has other advantages.